# Converting `os.system` to `subprocess` in Python

Tags: python, linux, bash, subprocess, gnu-screen

I want to grep a Linux Screen ID in Python to check if this Screen exists. I would like to convert my `os.system` command to `subprocess` command.

From this:

```py
os.system('screen -ls | grep -i ' + INSTANCE_NAME + ' >/dev/null')
```

to this:

```py
subprocess.check_call(['screen', '-ls', '|', 'grep', '-i', INSTANCE_NAME])
```

The `os.system` command works fine, but not the `subprocess` command. And what are the differences between `subprocess.run`, `subprocess.call` and `subprocess.check_call`? Can someone help me out?

I'm using Python 3.10 on Linux Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pipe `|` is a shell command that connects the output of a process to the input of another. If you want to use it in `subprocess`, you have to tell the `subprocess` function that you want to run the command in a shell like this:

```py
subprocess.check_call('screen -ls | grep -i ' + INSTANCE_NAME, shell=True)
```

If you use this, you should take into account the [security considerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations) of the shell invocation. If you want to achieve the same thing without a shell, you must use two subprocesses. Here is an example:

```py
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["screen", "-ls"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(
    ["grep", "-i", INSTANCE_NAME], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE
)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
output = p2.communicate()[0].decode()
```

(See https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline)

> And what are the differences between subprocess.run, subprocess.call and subprocess.check_call? Can someone help me out?

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) provides extensive information about the difference between these functions. The TL;DR is:

1. `call` and `check_call` are part of the old high-level API while `run` is the new recommended approach to invoke subprocesses.
2. `call`: runs a command and returns its return code
3. `check_call`: like call but raises an exception if the return code is not 0
4. `run`: well, you have access to the return code, the output, you can raise for non-zero codes, etc, etc. The documentation has all the information.

Comment: Note that rather than actually piping `screen` to `grep`, you could just run `screen` alone and search the results yourself (writing code equivalent to `grep` in Python is trivial).

Comment: @Niklas Glad you found the answer useful.

@ShadowRanger you are right, I would use python string operations and/or the `re` module instead of `grep`. That said I wrote the answer this way because the second subprocess could be anything, not necessarily `grep`.

Comment: It's a good answer, but we probably have hundreds of duplicates of the question in the knowledge base already. Do mind the note in the Answer Well-Asked Questions section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) about questions that have been "asked and answered many times before".

Comment: How would this looks like when I don't use `grep` and just use python and without using a shell?